# Sails.js Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: callback, http-headers, sails.js

I am using sailsjs v0.10.5.

I am trying to redirect to login after verifying user email and update the database before redirect.

I am using redirection in my update callback. But it sending the error after updating the database

```
'Cant send headers after they are sent'.
```

The following is the code am using for redirection:

```
verifyEmail: function(req, res){
var userId = req.param('userId');
User.update({id: userId},{isVerified: true}).exec(function(err, user) {
  if (!err) { 
      req.flash('error', 'Your email is verified please login');
      res.redirect('/login'); }else { return res.send(user, 400); }
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update waterline function is asynchronous, are you sure there isnt some res method later in the scope that may be fired before?

Answer (score 1):

Its recommended to use `return res.*` for so-called "terminal methods" see [http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/res/res.forbidden.html?q=notes](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/res/res.forbidden.html)