# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent in sails.js v0.11

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I have upgraded my project from sails v0.9.8 to sails v0.11. When do i try to retrive data, it gives this error.

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11)
>       at ServerResponse.appendHeader (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:94:33)
>       at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:125:19)
>       at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (/home/abc/xyz/git/propgod-internal-V0.11/clients/web/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:577:10)
>       at ServerResponse.res.cookie (/home/abc/xyz/git/propgod-internal-V0.11/clients/web/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:650:8)
>       at Request.callback [as _callback] (/home/abc/xyz/git/propgod-internal-V0.11/clients/web/api/services/DataService.js:51:34)
>       at Request.self.callback (/home/abc/xyz/git/propgod-internal-V0.11/clients/web/node_modules/request/request.js:123:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at Request. (/home/abc/xyz/git/propgod-internal-V0.11/clients/web/node_modules/request/request.js:1047:14)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/home/abc/xyz/git/propgod-internal-V0.11/clients/web/node_modules/request/request.js:998:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at _stream_readable.js:944:16
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13)
>
> ## .

How can i enable cors for my application?

Note : I'm loading scripts and styles using Gruntfile.js.
       I have separate modules for client and server side.

Please help me out !!!

Answer (score 1):

CORS is configured via config/cors.js but can be changed on a per route basis

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.cors.html

Depending on what your doing there are many reasons why you might getting the error message your asking about.

[setheader gives error: "throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404436/setheader-gives-error-throw-new-errorcan-t-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

[Sails.js Can't set headers after they are sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424515/sails-js-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

[sailsjs policy causing Can't set headers after they are sent error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528907/sailsjs-policy-causing-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-error)

Comment: As i mentioned that i have two modules api and client. so when do i make a call to api  controller from client module the response is coming  but at the same time error occurs (ie. i have asked). Its looking like the grunt file is not loading header files after response coming from api to client or sails is not able to make a CORS call between api or client or may be socket calling issue as in new sails version they have deprecated the methods as beforeConnect() and afterDisconnect() .